# Parse Query not registering class name

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm having trouble with querying Parse through the javascript SDK in Cloud Code. I have a class named "Stack" and "StackUser". Everything works fine until I get to querying "Stack". I am using the exact same syntax I used to query "StackUser". I am using the get method to get the stack object with an id. I have confirmed by logging in console that `stackpointer.id` is indeed a correct id.

However, this function never enters the `queryStack.get(stackPointer.id {` line. I have confirmed that the object stackPointer has correct information and as does `stackPointer.id`. I have also confirmed that control flow enters the for loop. It however does not enter the above mentioned line.

Help me out please. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getStacksForUser", function(request, response) {

    console.log(request);
    console.log(response);

    var StackUser = Parse.Object.extend("StackUser");
    var queryStackUser = new Parse.Query(StackUser);

    queryStackUser.equalTo("user", request.user);
    console.log("BEFORE FIND")

    queryStackUser.find({
        success: function(results) {
            console.log("DO WE HAVE RESULTS");
            console.log(results);
            var Stack = Parse.Object.extend("Stack");
            var queryStack = new Parse.Query(Stack);

            console.log("BEFORE LOOP");
            var stackarray = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
                var stackPointer = results[i].get("stack");
                queryStack.get(stackPointer.id, {
                    success: function(stack) {
                        console.log("STACK")
                        console.log(stack);
                        stackarray.push(stack);
                    },
                    error: function(object, error) {
                        console.log("ERROR!!!");
                        response.error("retrieving a stack failed");
                    }
                });

            }
            console.log("RESULT TIME");
            console.log(stackarray);
            response.success(stackarray);
        },
        error: function() {
            response.error("retrieving stacks failed");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `response.success()` will return a response to the client. You're calling this outside of a loop that uses multiple asynchronous `get()` methods, so it's no surprise that these `get()` queries are not given a chance to run.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll be much happier if you use promises. The code below has just been visually checked, but I believe it's close to what you want. I haven't actually had to use .when yet, so I might be confused about that. The inner error should probably be propagated to the last error clause too.

-Bob

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getStacksForUser", function(request, response) {

    console.log(request);
    console.log(response);

    var StackUser = Parse.Object.extend("StackUser");
    var queryStackUser = new Parse.Query(StackUser);

    queryStackUser.equalTo("user", request.user);
    console.log("BEFORE FIND")
    var stackarray = new Array();

    var promise0 = queryStackUser.find();
    promise1 = promise0.then(function(results){
        console.log("DO WE HAVE RESULTS");
        console.log(results);
        var Stack = Parse.Object.extend("Stack");
        var queryStack = new Parse.Query(Stack);

        console.log("BEFORE LOOP");
        var promiseArray = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
            promiseArray[i] = results[i].get("stack");
            promiseArray[i].then(function(result){
                console.log("STACK")
                console.log(stack);
                stackarray.push(stack);
            }, function(error){
                console.log("ERROR!!!");
                response.error("retrieving a stack failed");
            });
        };
        return Parse.Promise.when(promiseArray);
    });
    promise1.then(function(result){
        response.success();
    }, function(error){
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```